# How to get a stream object from the createReadStream function in a NodeJS response to Python script and save a file

Tags: python, node.js, express

I have some lines of code to return a large file from the NodeJS server below:

```
    const fileName = 'large.mp4';

    const readableStream = fs.createReadStream("./upload/" + fileName);

    readableStream.on('error', function (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        results.data = [];
        results.errorMessage = error.message;
    });

    readableStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(chunk);
    });

    results.data = readableStream;
    results.errorMessage = '';
    return results;
```

and this is the sample response with the return when executing these lines of code:

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
    "fd": null,
    "path": "./upload/cook.mp3",
    "flags": "r",
    "mode": 438,
    "end": null,
    "bytesRead": 0,
    "closed": false,
    "_readableState": {
        "objectMode": false,
        "highWaterMark": 65536,
        "buffer": {
            "head": null,
            "tail": null,
            "length": 0
        },
        "length": 0,
        "pipes": [],
        "flowing": true,
        "ended": false,
        "endEmitted": false,
        "reading": false,
        "constructed": false,
        "sync": true,
        "needReadable": true,
        "emittedReadable": false,
        "readableListening": false,
        "resumeScheduled": false,
        "errorEmitted": false,
        "emitClose": true,
        "autoDestroy": true,
        "destroyed": false,
        "errored": null,
        "closed": false,
        "closeEmitted": false,
        "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
        "awaitDrainWriters": null,
        "multiAwaitDrain": false,
        "readingMore": false,
        "dataEmitted": false,
        "decoder": null,
        "encoding": null
    },
    "_events": {},
    "_eventsCount": 3
}
}
```

From another side, I write some Python lines of code to receive this above response and save it to a file.

```
import http.client
import json
import io
import shutil

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost", 3025)
#conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("localhost", 3025)
payload = json.dumps({
  "serverId": "1234"
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
conn.request("POST", "/api/getStreamDataByServerId", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
dataConvert =  json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
read_buffer = io.BytesIO(dataConvert["data"]) #I'm stucking to get stream data from there

with open('test.mp4', 'wb') as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(read_buffer, file)
```

Now, I don't know how can get stream data from this JSON object and parse it into a file.
Actually, I'm a beginner with Python, I need more of your solution.

Thanks for reading...